# How to add up values in list based on a certain value in the list?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and each list has the following items:

`site, count, time
sample data: site1, 15, 20`

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this. I want to add up the count and time for each site.

I thought converting it to a dictionary when I iterate through each list, but I'm not sure what that gives me.

`for site, count, time in lists:
   #create a dictionary, then what?`

The end result, I'd like either a list or dictionary (some kind of data structure I can use) with the count and time for each site added up into a "total" list for each sites.

Ex: 
`site, total_count, total_time`

`sample data:
site1, 50, 100 #all data for site1 added up
site2, 40, 300 #all data for site2 added up`

Not looking for a coded answer, just the best way to get this done and a point in the right direction.

Comment: The question is very ambiguous.  Are you going to iterate over each site and report out its count and time, or do you want the total count for all sites and total time for all sites?  Need much more info.  If you can provide some example data that would help

Comment: Added some more info. I'm going to end up iterating over each site at the end and doing somehing with the data. I need a total_count and total_time for each site.

Comment: Is it a flat list? Or a list of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of lists (better make it a list of tuples instead) and add the count and time to the total count and total time in the output dict with site as the key:

```
lists = [
    ('site1', 15, 20),
    ('site2', 10, 30),
    ('site1', 5, 25),
    ('site1', 30, 55),
    ('site2', 30, 270)
]
result = {}
for site, count, time in lists:
    total_count, total_time = result.get(site, (0, 0))
    result[site] = (total_count + count, total_time + time)
```

`result` becomes:

```
{'site1': (50, 100), 'site2': (40, 300)}
```

Comment: This is the answer I went with because I think it worked well for the situation. Other answers were good to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You said some kind of data structure, so maybe construct a `DataFrame` out of the lists that you have and then use the `groupby` followed by `sum`, to get what you want.

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['site1',15,20],['site1',35,80],['site2',15,20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['site','time','count'])
print(df.groupby('site').sum())
```

**Output**

```
       time  count
site              
site1    50    100
site2    15     20
```

**Alternatively**:

```
data = [['site1',15,20],['site1',35,80],['site2',15,20]]
data_d = {}
for rec in data:
    if rec[0] in data_d:
        data_d[rec[0]][0] += rec[1]
        data_d[rec[0]][1] += rec[2]
    else:
        data_d[rec[0]] = rec[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is still a little ambiguous but, for example, you could build a class that uses a dictionary of dictionaries.  It can aggregate data in an iterative manner by adding data to it like this:

```
>>> class SiteAggregator:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.sites = {}
...     def __call__(self, data):
...             site_name, site_counts, site_time = data
...             if site_name not in self.sites:
...                     self.sites[site_name] = {'counts':0, 'time':0}
...             self.sites[site_name]['counts'] += site_counts
...             self.sites[site_name]['time'] += site_time
...
>>> site_agg = SiteAggregator()
>>> site_agg(['a', 20, 22])
>>> site_agg(['b', 10, 13])
>>> site_agg.sites['a']
{'counts': 20, 'time': 22}
>>> site_agg(['a', 10, 12])
>>> site_agg.sites['a']
{'counts': 30, 'time': 34}
>>> sites = [['a', 20, 10], ['b', 30, 15], ['c', 18, 22], ['a', 15, 22], ['b', 10, 2]]
>>> for site in sites:
...     site_agg(site)
...
>>> site_agg.sites['a']
{'counts': 65, 'time': 66}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the following would be a right approach to sovle this problem.

```
import json # For pretty priting dictionary

# List of lists where each sub list contains site, count, time in order
data_list = [
    ["mysite1.com", 11, 88],
    ["mysite1.com", 7, 6],
    ["google.com", 6, 23],
    ["mysite2.com", 9, 12],
    ["google.com", 4, 7],
    ['mysite1.com', 9, 12],
    ['mysite2.com', 13, 4]
];

d = {}

for l in data_list:
    site, count, time = l # Unpacking

    if site in d:
        # APPEND/UPDATE VALUES
        d[site]["count"].append(count)
        d[site]["time"].append(time)
    else:
        # CREATE NEW KEYS WITH DATA
        d[site] = {
            "count": [count],
            "time": [time]
        }

    d[site]["total_count"] = sum(d[site]["count"])
    d[site]["total_time"] = sum(d[site]["time"])

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

# {
#     "mysite1.com": {
#         "count": [
#             11,
#             7,
#             9
#         ],
#         "time": [
#             88,
#             6,
#             12
#         ],
#         "total_count": 27,
#         "total_time": 106
#     },
#     "google.com": {
#         "count": [
#             6,
#             4
#         ],
#         "time": [
#             23,
#             7
#         ],
#         "total_count": 10,
#         "total_time": 30
#     },
#     "mysite2.com": {
#         "count": [
#             9,
#             13
#         ],
#         "time": [
#             12,
#             4
#         ],
#         "total_count": 22,
#         "total_time": 16
#     }
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky approach (inspired by electric engineering): use a Counter whose values are complex numbers; the real part is time, imaginary part is count. ;-)